# Почему на фриланс-площадках постоянно появляются заказы на сбор apk-файлов мобильных приложений?

Tags: android, apk

Постоянно на фриланс-площадках появляются заказы на сбор apk-файлов мобильных приложений.

Почему они сами не могут собрать свое приложение?
Можно ли получить бан по железу (ну в случае если приложение нарушает правила Google Play)?

Comment: Да, баны по железу имеют место быть. И да, в этих случаях разумный выход - собирать на незабаненном гуглом железе.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ну я в принципе так и подумал

Comment: Объясните что такое "бан по железу"?